# Does Microsoft offer a corporate IM/collaboration tool similar to Campfire? My googlefu skills appear to be failing me today

Tags: windows

I mentioned to my boss that we should look into a single unified IM client that we could use and secure on a corporate level, and then suggested Campfire.

We're a primarily Microsoft house so he suggested we use something that would better integrate with SharePoint and the other tools our end users use in house. However, I'm not aware of any Microsoft tool that does something like this. Obviously there is MSN Messenger but I think/hope he wasn't referring to that.

Other than a product from 2005 I haven't been able to locate a Microsoft corporate IM tool...does anybody know what he may have been talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft Lync (previously Office Communications Server) provides IM functionality (including group chats, screen sharing, and the like) as well as VOIP functionality.  It's not cheap, and it's not easy to deploy (in my experience), but it integrates nicely with Exchange and SharePoint (so, for instance, you get nice little smart-tags next to people's names on a SharePoint site that show you if they're available and allow you to kick off a chat, email or call directly).  They're offering it on a SaaS basis now, so it may be much cheaper and easier to deploy than it used to be -- worth looking into, in any case.

Comment: Excellent, this must be what he was refering to...I appreciate your help!